# Email is not accessible on GitHubProvider in next-auth

Tags: next.js, null, runtime-error, prisma, next-auth

I try to integrate GitHub as way of logging into my next.js application, but currently I am facing:

```
Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
+   email: String
  }
}

Argument `email` must not be null.
```

I have configured my authOptions like this:

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

And I am trying to access it here:

```
async function Dashboard() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  console.log(session);
  
  if (!session) redirect("/api/auth/signin");

  const currentUserEmail = session?.user?.email!;
  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: currentUserEmail,
    },
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <ProfileForm user={user} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

in the session object, **the email is null**

I have also changed the app configuration inside GitHub to be able to read-only email addresses, but it still doesn't work. Please help me solve this issue. Thank you!

P.S. my email in github is set to private, so this also might be a factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially when creating project in Neon database, I stored the user, without email, so on each new signup, it was basically retrieving the same instance from the database, where the email was null, so I removed all the tokens from the github app(just in case), deleted the database, re-do it, connected it with prisma again, migrated prisma & now the email is showing...